# How to select two event name values in where condition

Tags: google-bigquery

How to select two event name (`screen_view` & `pushnot`) in a where condition from Google bigquery. I tried the query below but it is not working.

```
Select event_name from <table> where event_name='screen_view' and 'pushnot'
```

Comment: provide example of your data and expected result

Comment: Hi Mikhail: I want to select specific event name from firebase analytics through bigquery. I tried select event_

Comment: As @MikhailBerlyant pointed out to me in my rushed stupidity, event_name can't = 'screen_name' AND ='pushnot'. If you provide some sample data and show what results you expect to be shown then it'll be easier for people to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is literally your query, it is a syntax error, you may try:

```
select event_name 
from <table> 
where event_name IN('screen_view','pushnot')
```

Alternatively:

```
select event_name 
from <table> 
where event_name ='screen_view' 
or  event_name ='pushnot'
```

If this is not what you are looking for, providing an example of the expected result, as mentioned in the comments, would be useful.

Note: `screen_view` is a predifined event name, while `pushnot` is a custom event

Comment: check the `firebase analytics` sample data in BigQuery to see why this is not the answer

Comment: Thanks Dave for the nice Support. Both the queries provided by you is working fine.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, I believe you mean "screen_name" and "pushnot" are not valid values for `event_name`, am I correct? It would be interesting to know how he ended up having these values (if that's the case). I'm not aware if custom events can be set. I don't see anything in the Firebase documentation about that.

Comment: @RamakrishnanM, would you mind sharing your thoughts on this?

Comment: what I meant was - OP using firebase analytics data and it's schema is different. but nevertheless - OP stated that it worked for him, so I might was wrong with my comment :o) but to be honest - I think OP just too junior to even assess correctness of the answer - just guessing - still can be wrong here :o)

Comment: According to this [document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) there is actually an  `event_name` column. I guess this is the schema OP is using.

Comment: Mikhail, It is not screen_name, it is "screen_view" and "pushnot" is a custom event name. Anyway thanks Mike,Mikhail for your support

Comment: @ch_mike - i see - so I was wrong and was looking into wrong sample data