# How to create a report in Biquery with param.key value “action” & “label” in two different columns

Tags: google-bigquery

**Queried  param.key “action” with string values via through big query by using below query and fetch the report**

select event_name, param.value.string_value as action,count(*) as eventcoun
From `<table>`,
UNNEST (event_params) as param
where event_name = 'BotNav' and param.key='action' group by 1,2 order by eventcount desc

**Output  received through bigquery**

event_name    action   eventount

BotNav         Home        3575

BotNav         App         1468

**Queried  param.key “label” with string values via through big query by using below query and fetch the report**

select event_name, param.value.string_value as action,count(*) as eventcoun
From `<table>`,
UNNEST (event_params) as param
where event_name = 'BotNav' and param.key='label' group by 1,2 order by eventcount desc

**output received through bigquery** 
event_name     label      eventount

BotNav         click      2341

BotNav         submit     1234

BotNav         click     1234 
BotNav         submit     234

**How to create  a report with event.param .key “action” & “label” in two different columns. I need to out in Bigquery like this.  Pls. find below the expected output in bigquery**

**Expected Output**

event_name     action     label      eventount

BotNav         Home        click      2341

BotNav         Home        submit     1234

BotNav         App          click     1234

BotNav         App          submit     234

**Pls Help to get the action & label string value in two different columns.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
#standardSQL
select 
  event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as action,
  param2.value.string_value as label,
  count(1) as eventcount
From `<table>`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2
where event_name = 'BotNav' 
and param1.key='action' 
and param2.key='label' 
group by 1, 2, 3 
order by eventcount desc
```

**obviously assuming** the only one 'action' and 'label' keys in event_params per event_name row - which should be true based on count numbers from examples in question

Another option would be

```
#standardSQL
select 
  event_name, 
  (select value.string_value from UNNEST(event_params) where key='action') as action,
  (select value.string_value from UNNEST(event_params) where key='label') as label,
  count(1) as eventcount
From `<table>`
where event_name = 'BotNav' 
group by 1, 2, 3 
order by eventcount desc
```

with same assumption

Comment: Mikhail, thanks for the response, but bigquery showing red error dot before line No. 4 param2.value.string_value as label, for the First option provided by you sir. Pls. help

Comment: I was writing on-go so it is possible  - give me sec - i will check

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for your quick response. Very kind of you Sir

Comment: I just checked second query and it also works for me - so give me the exact error you see!

Comment: Yes Mikhail both options  are working Fine. Thank you for the awesome support. My salute to you Sir

Comment: Mikhail Sir: I put two queries in stackoverflow related to bigquery. Sir, is it possible to help me on this. Once again thanks for your support sir in advance. Pls. find below the query link Sir.   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409115/how-to-fetch-firebase-event-screen-view-metrics-in-bigquery-unique-screenviews

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411760/shall-i-use-special-characters-in-firebase-param-value-event-params-value-strin

Comment: sure. i will check out those questions too, meantime  - please accept the answer as it is a real way of saying 'thank you' on SO. if you would have enough reputation  - you would also be able to vote up the answer. but for now at least accept it

Comment: Mikhail Sir:I am new to stackoverflow. Sir, I don't know how to accept the answer. which button i need to click in stackoverflow to accept the answer... Do i need to click "active"...  Pls. Help. Sorry for asking these silly questions...

Comment: sure, no problem - give me a sec - i will point you to some quick summary on this :o)

Comment: Mikhail Sir: I am following you in twitter & dropped you a thank you message in twitter

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Accepted. In future, all the solutions, I will accept immediately. Thank Sir for patiently teaching me. Very kind of you Sir.

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Accepted. Pls. check the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396412/how-to-select-two-event-name-values-in-where-condition

Comment: Btw, you don't have to do this immediately, cause you can loose other answers that can potentially be even better than first or second one  - but definitelly in some reasonable timeframe you should accept the best answer (and also vote up it and other helpful answers) - this increase your own reputation and at the same time motivates us to answer your new/next questions :o) hope you got an idea - read again the link I provided you in one of previous comments. good night for now :o) - i will check your other questions tomorrow morning :o)

Comment: Good Night Mikhail Sir. Take Care. Also love to reach you on twitter. I already message you.

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Tomorrow, Can you pls help me with this below query.  In Google analytics, we can get two metrics from events Total events & unique events. How to get Unique Events from Bigquery Via firebase analytics. Thanks

Comment: if yo have new question - you should post it as a separate new question instead of using comments :o) please do and I or someone will gladly answer it

Comment: Mikhail Sir: As advised posted as new / separate question. Pls find below the link for your kind reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441327/how-to-query-firebase-analytics-unique-event-count-in-bigquery

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Requesting your support for below query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951487/how-to-query-multiple-firebase-projects-in-bigquery