# How to Query Unique Events & Unique screenviews from Bigquery in Firebase Analytics

Tags: google-bigquery

In  Google Analytics, We have two key metrics in respect of events & screens.
Events Metrics - Total Events & Unique Events
Screenview Metrics - Total Screenviews & Unique Screenviews

How to query Unique Events & Unique screenviews from Biquery

Events - Unique Events

Extracted total Total Events by query below in Bigquery...  But how to query Unique Events.

```
select 
app_info.id,app_info.version,  
event_date,event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as category,
  count(1) as totalevents
From `<table>`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1
where param1.key='category' 

group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
order by totalevents desc
```

Requesting your support on how to query Unique events from Bigquery

Screen - Unique screenviews

Extracted total screenviews by query below in Bigquery...  But how to query unique screenviews.

```
select app_info.id,app_info.version,event_date,event_name, param.value.string_value as firebase_screen,count(*) as screen_views
From `<table>`,
UNNEST (event_params) as param
WHERE event_name = 'screen_view' and param.key='firebase_screen'group by 1,2,3,4,5 order by screen_views desc
```

Requesting your support on how to query Unique Screenviews from Bigquery

Comment: Mikhail Sir: I will try using "distinct" option in the query & get back....I should not bug you without trying... Sorry

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Tried few options, i am unsuccessful, Pls. help

Comment: Mikhail Sir: Requesting your support for below query. Pls. Help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956102/how-to-use-unnest-params-in-google-data-studio-how-to-create-firebase-event-re

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your question follows what you're trying to accomplish in the query snippets you've posted.

Following your queries, you're trying to count events with particular parameter values. Here is how I would do that:

```
select
  event_name,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST (event_params) WHERE key = "action") AS action,
  count(1) as event_count
from `<table>` 
where event_name = "BotNav"
group by 1,2
order by event_count desc
```

In case you are actually just looking for a way to count the number of events, here is how I would do it:

```
select
  event_name,
  count(1) as event_count
from `<table>`
group by 1
order by event_count desc
```

Please be more clear to what you're asking. Maybe you could post how you want the resulting query to look like to give us an idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: HI Sir: Thanks for the response. There is a metrics called "Unique Users" in Datastudio. How to query the "Unique Users" metrics through bigquery. Pls. find attached the datastudio dimension & metrics screenshot for your kind reference. Pls. help