# How to use UNNEST Params in Google Data Studio - How to create Firebase event report with UNNEST action & label params in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

We extract event report with param name action & label  by querying below in Bigquery

```
#standardSQL
select 
  event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as action,
  param2.value.string_value as label,
  count(1) as eventcount
From `<table>`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2
where event_name = 'BotNav' 
and param1.key='action' 
and param2.key='label' 
group by 1, 2, 3 
order by eventcount desc
```

**But, How to fetch this report via data studio. How to UNNEST Param in google data studio. I am able to filter event param name contains action & label in google datastudio. But i am unable to unnest the action & label in data studio. Due to this I am unable to correlate action & label elements. Pls help

Pls find below the google data studio report screenshot for your kind reference**
[datastudio report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFP64.gif)

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is, but you can use a custom query from Data Studio; see [the documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks Elliott for your support. You answered my question.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you figured it out. To help future readers, consider adding an answer to your own question describing what you did.

Comment: I run the query by pasting the query in Custom query interface &  got the output report in data studio. Thanks for the useful link

Comment: Elliott: Can you pls. help me on this question Pls. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037021/in-bigquery-how-to-query-yesterday-data-last-7-days-data-from-firebase-event