# In Bigquery - How to query Yesterday data & Last 7 days data from Firebase event table

Tags: google-bigquery

I use below query to fetch data for specified data range.

```
SELECT event_date, count(event_name) as APP_Installs FROM 
`<Table>.events_*`  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '201900201'  AND '20190228' 
and event_name='first_open' group by 1
```

- How to  query  event table for yesterday data without mentioned the
  date value in Bigquery?
- How to  query  event table for last 7 days data without mentioned the
  date value in Bigquery?

Pls. Help

Comment: use current date and other date function to create last day and last 7 day

Comment: I know it's an old question, but just to point out, when you typed those dates in by hand, you added an extra `0`...  `'201900201'` should have been `'20190201'`

Answer (score 8):

[Date functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) are what you need here.

To look at the last 7 days, use the following query:

```
SELECT event_date, count(event_name) as APP_Installs 
FROM `<Table>.events_*`  
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
AND event_name = 'first_open'
GROUP BY 1
```

To look at yesterday's data, use the following query:

```
SELECT event_date, count(event_name) as APP_Installs 
FROM `<Table>.events_*`  
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND event_name = 'first_open'
GROUP BY 1
```