# How to fetch specific param value in Param key through bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How to fetch specfic param value through bigquery. I tried to fetch a specific value from event.param.key=firebase_screen and the firebase_screen value is "Matches-List". Below query is showing error. Pls. help.

```
select 
      event_name, 
      param1.value.string_value as firebase_screen,
      param2.value.int_value as engagement_time_msec
    From `<table>`,
    UNNEST(event_params) as param1 where firebase_screen='Matches-List'
    UNNEST(event_params) as param2
    where event_name = 'user_engagement' 
    and param1.key='firebase_screen'
    and param2.key='engagement_time_msec' 
    group by 1, 2, 3 
    order by engagement_time_msec desc
```

Pls. Help

Comment: What is the error? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Hi Elliott, thanks for your response. Is the query syntax is right? i am  trying to fetch the firebase_screename='Matches-List'  UNNEST(event_params) as param1 where firebase_screen='Matches-List' I am getting the error in Line No.7 (A red dot)

Comment: It's not clear why you can't just use or modify the answer from the previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53424730/6253347

Comment: HI Elliott: Thanks for your response.  This question is bit different(not the same)from the other. How to fetch specific param values from specific Param key? (But i don't know the syntax of how to query specific param key value 'Matches-List' from param key 'firebase_screen' . I tried above query, but it is showing error (red dot) in line no 7. Pls help

Comment: HI Elliott: Found the solution. Thanks for your support

Comment: Thanks Elliott for your support. Found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, Below query works. Thanks for your support.

```
select 
  event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as firebasescreen,
  param2.value.int_value as engagement_time_msec
From `<table>`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2
where event_name = 'user_engagement' 
and param1.key='firebase_screen'
and param2.key='engagement_time_msec'
and param1.value.string_value ='Matches-List'
group by 1, 2, 3 
order by engagement_time_msec desc
```